# Add conditional in a for loop

Tags: conditional, forloop

I need to add a separator if there are a multiple of types. How can this be done in a for loop?

```
{% for type in entry.buildType %}{{ type }}{% endfor %}
```

The outcome is similar to a breadcrumb nav, with an added "/", however the separator should only be placed in between - not for the last.

Comment: Twig also has a very useful [join filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/join.html), which does exactly this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% for type in entry.buildType %}
{{ type }}
{% if not loop.last %}/{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

See: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable